# How to put in labels in list for R?

Tags: list, r, label

I am using R currently and I want to know how can I label the list objects when 
I declare a list. For example: `return(list(xhat,alpha,beta))`, and `xhat`, `alpha` and `beta`
are themselves arrays. I want to give each an appropriate label.

Thank you.

Answer (score 26):

For simple cases Michael's answer will work. Sometimes though you have a vector of names `my_names` which you would like to use to name/rename the output. There are at least three ways:

- use `names<-`:

  ```
  out <- list(xhat,alpha,beta)  
  names(out) <- my_names  
  out
  ```
- use `setNames()`:

  ```
  setNames(out, my_names)
  ```
- use `structure()`:

  ```
  structure(out, names=my_names)
  ```

Comment: None of those need `return()`, and will cause an Error if issued at the top level (i..e not within a function)

Comment: @Gavin, obviously so, but his question is about labeling the returned value, so return is there to match the question.

Comment: Return is optional in r and it's good style to omit it, except when used for early exit

Comment: Ok, removed `return()` from the answer, for clarity.

Answer (score 10):

All you need is `list(x=xhat, a=alpha, b=beta)`

Comment: Yes but I want  to label the output.

Comment: When you select each element of the list by using eg `list.name["x"]` the name (here `x`) gets printed with the output. When you use two brackets the name gets omitted `list.name[["x"]]`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: All the ways suggested by VitoshKa and me make a list with labelled elements. The way I suggested works if you know the labels ahead of time. VitoshKa's solutions are more general, so will work when you want to determine the labels within your script. What you do with these labels is another question...

Comment: @[George Tyler] You were quiet clear in question "how can I label the list objects when I **declare** a list". So you want to name existing object (VitoshKa answer) or add names when declaring it (Michael answer)?